# "The Arthur's code" or "The code of Arthur"?

Tags: possessives

Arthur is a very good doctor and he created a good conduct code for all the other doctors in the world.

Should he call its code "The code of Arthur" or "The Arthur's code"?

Comment: Based on the example of the Hippocratic Oath, it should be the Arthurian Code.

Comment: @HotLicks, surely you can't be serious!

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: why not? It was my first thought as well.

Comment: It's already taken! -- ***The Arthurian Code***  *At the beginning of his reign, Arthur makes his knights swear an oath which they are to renew annually*.   An Introduction to Malory
 By Terence McCarthy https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9ZEXCTQWi9cC&pg=PA72&dq=Arthurian+code+of+chivalry&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Arthurian%20code%20of%20chivalry&f=false

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - That's "Shirley"!!

Comment: The, er, *New* Arthurian Code ?

Comment: But note that if you use _the_ with a possessive, _the_ attaches to the possessor, not the possessed: _the boys' room_, _the Smiths' house_, _the man's hand_. If you said _The Arthur's code_ this would mean a code connected with "The Arthur", which would be a very unusual thing to say.

Comment: Usually would use the surname.  It's called a Turing Test, not an Alan Test, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It depends how big-headed he is. If he invented it for himself and never intended to publish it then he would probably call it **Arthur's code**.

If he has delusions of grandeur and intends to impose it on others and insists on using his own name then I suggest, **The Arthur Code.**

Of course other people might name it **The Arthur Code** in his honour even if he himself didn't have a name for it.